# Distributed processing of JSON in Hadoop

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to process a ~300 GB JSON file in Hadoop. As far as my understanding goes a JSON consists of a single string with data nested in it. Now if I want to parse the JSON string using Google's GSON, then won't the Hadoop have to put the entire load upon a single node as the JSON is not logically divisible for it.

How do I partition the file (I can make out the partitions logically looking at the data) if I want that it should be processed parallely on different nodes. Do I have to break the file before I load it onto HDFS itself. Is it absolutely necessary that the JSON is parsed by one machine (or node) at least once?

Comment: Take a look at the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942483/hadoop-for-json-files. The dzone article provides insight on processing XML and JSON in Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know can logically parse the JSON into logical separate components then you can accomplish this just by writing your own InputFormat.

Conceptually you can think of each of the logically divisible JSON components as one "line" of data. Where each component contains the minimal amount of information that can be acted on independently.

Then you will need to make a class, a FileInputFormat, where you will have to return each of these JSON components.

```
public class JSONInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text,JSONComponent {...}
```

Comment: This seems like a good choice, even after being logically divisible, the first few lines are common for all the sub-parts into which I can divide the JSON. I have written my own `FileInputFormat` before, but I am not sure if I can read a file in such a way that each part retains the first few lines.

Comment: An idea, If there is only a couple of common variables maybe you could read those first lines and distribute them to all InputFormats using the distributed cache. Another idea, you could keep those "header" sections in a separate file entirely, and merge those JSON nodes back in after reading in the JSON parts

Answer (score 0):

If you can logically divide your giant JSON into parts, do it, and save these parts as separate lines in file (or records in sequence file). Then, if you feed this new file to Hadoop MapReduce, mappers will be able to process records in parallel.

So, yes, JSON should be parsed by one machine at least once. This preprocessing phase doesn't need to be performed in Hadoop, simple script can do the work. Use streaming API to avoid loading a lot of data into memory.

Comment: But processing a ~300 GB file requires a lot of resources. Can you elaborate the streaming API part?

Comment: Streaming API for JSON is similar with XML's one. You just read entire file token by token, keeping in memory only small part of tokens needed at the moment. Concrete usage case highly depends on your data structure. For Jackson Streaming API examples see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi, http://prithvi-java.blogspot.ru/2012/08/jackson-json-streaming-api.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713990/how-to-parse-json-log-file-with-streaming-api-in-java-then-output-tabulated-log, http://blog.avisi.nl/2012/11/29/jackson-and-parsing-streams-a-short-story-about-a-big-pile-o-json/

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [JSON SerDe](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) useful. It allows hive to read and write in JSON format. If it works for you, it'll be a lot more convenient to process you JSON data with Hive as you don't have to worry about the custom InputFormat that is going to read your JSON data and create splits for you.